glue not find .x in map together with partial function
I have modified glue using purrr::partial and it works fine except when I try to using it together with purrr::map. There are multiple workaround but I'm confused on why this does not work?
library(purrr)
library(glue)


glue_css <- partial(glue, .open = "{{", .close = "}}")
a <- 5

glue_css("{{a}}") #OK

map(c("id1", "id2"), ~glue("{{.x}} {a}", .open = "{{", .close = "}}")) #OK
glue_css("{{a}} {a}") # OK
map(c("id1", "id2"), ~glue_css("{{.x}} {a}")) #.x not found


add .envir = parent.frame() to the partial function, otherwise it cannot access the environment where .x has been defined.

Just following the purrr:map help recommendation.
# Instead of
x |> map(f, 1, 2, collapse = ",")
# do:
x |> map(\(x) f(x, 1, 2, collapse = ","))

for you case, I tried in my computer it works by using the new style of coding style.
library(purrr)
library(glue)


glue_css <- partial(glue, .open = "{{", .close = "}}")
a <- 5

glue_css("{{a}}") #OK

ids <- c("id1", "id2")
ids |> 
  map(\(x) glue("{{x}} {{a}}", .open = "{{", .close = "}}")) #OK

if you like my answer, pls vote it up.

@julian may I know why down vote the answer?  your answer will help me improve. thanks you very much
